# Saving one graph when R gives more than one at once

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have been using `quartz.save()` to save graphs that I have been making in R. However, sometimes R gives you more than one graph at once, saying `Hit <Return> to see next plot:` in the console.

How would I go about saving all (or just one) of these graphs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option that's available for all of R's file-based graphics devices.

It's documented, among other places, in the `filename=` section of the [`?png` help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html).

```
png("image %01d.png")
example(image)        # Produces four plots
dev.off()

# List the files produced by the above
dir(pattern = "png$")
# [1] "image 1.png" "image 2.png" "image 3.png" "image 4.png"
```